# Delete property of an array object using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array object in the below format and need to delete a property of an array.

**Code:**

```
var partDetailArray={[PartId:100,PartRowID:'row-1']
,[PartId:100,PartRowID:'row-1']};
delete partDetailsArray.PartRowID;
```

I need to remove the `PartRowID` property from the array, but the `delete` statement isn't working.

Comment: That code is invalid. You can't have `{[...]}` like that, the `{}` starts an object initializer, but then you have an array initializer inside it, which contains property initializers. There are two aspects of that which are invalid. 1. You can't have the array initializer there, you'd have to have a property name and a colon in front of it. 2. You can't have property initializers like that inside an array initializer.

Comment: This is not even valid javascript object

Comment: Yes, my mistake. the brackets got misplaced. It worked .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the console, you'll see that you're getting syntax errors with that code for the reasons I put in my comment on the question.

I'm going to guess you meant to have an array containing objects, like this:

```
var partDetailArray = [
    {PartId:100,PartRowID:'row-1'},
    {PartId:100,PartRowID:'row-1'}
];
```

In that case, the array doesn't have a `PartRowID` property, but each of the objects in it does. So we need to index into the array to access the object, and delete the property from it:

```
delete partDetailsArray[0].PartRowID;
// Indexing into it ---^^^
```

That would delete that property from the first one. If you want to delete all of them, you'll need a loop:

```
var index;
for (index = 0; index < partDetailArray.length; ++index) {
    delete partDetailsArray[index].PartRowID;
}
```